# What is the difference between importing selection.json and SVG sprite to Icomoon?

Tags: json, svg, icons

I recently created an icon font using [Icomoon app](http://icomoon.io/app). The generated font is intended to be used by the whole developer team, so they can add more icons and just commit the new font and CSS files. I understand that this could be achieved with the import feature Icomoon has provided.

However, knowing that we can import either the generated font/SVG sprite or the selection.json file, I'm curious whether those files produce the same outcome when imported to Icomoon. Which file should I import to Icomoon to ensure consistency, if I want to add more icons to the font set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the selection.json file. It contains all your settings. The SVG font would work fine too, but in some cases, it might not contain your preferences/settings.